# Summation problem (not sure of my solution)

Tags: summation

If $f(x)=3-x$, evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^3f(2k)$.

So this is my solution:

$f[2(3-1)]=4$

$f[2(3-2)]=2$

$f[2(3-3)]=0$

So the required sum is $4+2+0=\boxed{6}$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: No, you are applying f first  then doubling.  The brackets say you should double first  then apply '3-' to that.

Answer (score 1):

That's Wrong.

If $f(x) = 3-x$ then $f(2x) \neq 2(3-x)$ but rather $f(2x) = 3-2x$.

So if you have some function $g(x)$ as the input of $f$ , then you need to replace all the $x$ in $f(x)$ into $g(x)$

Answer (score 1):

With $f(x)=3-x$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^3f(2k)}&=f(2\cdot1)+f(2\cdot 2) + f(2\cdot 3)\\
&=f(2)+f(4)+f(6)\\
&=(3-2)+(3-4)+(3-6)\\
&=1-1-3\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=-3}
\end{align*}